# Kill a Thread working with flag in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop, datagram

I implemented my own Thread in Java this way :

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    protected boolean exit = false;

    protected void kill(){
        exit = true;
 }
}
```

So when I create a thread, the method run() looks like :

```
public void run() {
    ...
    while(!exit) {
    ...
    }
}
```

My question is the following : I'm using my thread class to receive and send datagrams. But when the thread is waiting for a datagram, if I call the function MyThread.kill(), the thread will still wait a next packet before ending itself... **How can I kill my thread without waiting for an another packet ?**
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the exit flag, send the thread a datagram yourself to unblock it. By the way, `exit` should be `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to **interrupt** a call to `DatagramSocket.receive()` is to close the socket, and `receive()` will then [throw a `SocketException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#close()). So after setting the `exit` flag, you should close the UDP socket in your `kill()` method.